# Can someone explain me how to use the cookie example from the redux-effects page?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm not sure how to get a cookie, actually I'm not sure how to access its value. As I understand, there is a middleware that returns a resolved `Promise` with the value of the cookie:

```
import cookie from 'component-cookie'

export default function ({dispatch, getState}) {
  return next => action => {
    if (action.type !== 'COOKIE') {
      return next(action)
    }

    switch (action.verb) {
      case 'set':
        return Promise.resolve(cookie(action.name, action.value))
      case 'get':
        return Promise.resolve(cookie(action.name))
    }
  }
}
```

What is not clear, how to read its value from a reducer for example?

See more on [their github](https://github.com/redux-effects/redux-effects#example---simple-cookie-middleware).

Comment: after you've added the middleware, you can listen for the 'COOKIE' action in your reducers and add whatever it returns to your state.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I ended up using this https://github.com/redux-effects/redux-effects-cookie